# How do I create a column in Pandas dataframe, which is a numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, and I want to add a new column, and to make the column of type numpy array.

For example this will create a column of type `int64` : `df['weight'] = 0`

I've tried something like `df['weight'] = np.zeros(1)`, hoping it will propagate the array to all the cells, like it did with the `0` but it didn't work

Comment: @Ch3steR I think OP wants each cell of that column to contain an ndarray

Comment: `df['weight'] = [np.zeros(1)]` or `df['weight'] = [np.zeros(1)]*len(df)` but why?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Sorry, my bad misunderstood the question.